# super-linter cannot find submodule for linting

Tags: github-actions, super-linter

Working with `super-linter` in a GitHub Actions workflow, this is a portion of it:

```yaml
- name: Clone repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    submodules: recursive
    fetch-depth: 0

- name: Super-linter
  uses: super-linter/super-linter@v5.7.2
  env:
    DEFAULT_BRANCH: develop
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The submodule is downloaded successfully to folder `src/components` but `super-linter` cannot find it:

```
2024-01-19 15:56:20 [INFO]   Gathering user validation information...
2024-01-19 15:56:20 [INFO]   - Validating ALL files in code base...
2024-01-19 15:56:25 [INFO]   ---------------------------------
2024-01-19 15:56:25 [INFO]   ------ File list to check: ------
2024-01-19 15:56:25 [INFO]   ---------------------------------
2024-01-19 15:56:27 [WARN]   File:{/github/workspace/src/components} existed in commit data, but not found on file system, skipping...
2024-01-19 15:56:29 [INFO]   ----------------------------------------------
2024-01-19 15:56:29 [INFO]   Successfully gathered list of files...
```

`super-linter` scans only the parent repo without the submodule.

Any help with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try configuring the [FILTER_REGEX_INCLUDE](https://github.com/super-linter/super-linter?tab=readme-ov-file#include-or-exclude-files-from-checks) env variable?

Comment: i have tested with this parameter, but without success.

Comment: Try: [`USE_FIND_ALGORITHM: true`](https://github.com/super-linter/super-linter?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-super-linter)

Comment: thank you, that worked for me, now i can lint all my submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `USE_FIND_ALGORITHM` to `true` which is `false` by default to lint all the files.

According to [`USE_FIND_ALGORITHM`](https://github.com/super-linter/super-linter?tab=readme-ov-file#configure-super-linter):

> By default, we use `git diff` to find all files in the workspace and what has been updated, this would enable the Linux `find` method instead to find all files to lint

That is what you've been observing i.e. only the updated files are linted. Switching to `find` with this will include everything and that is what you're looking for.